# Printing last element in an array using if statement

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, if-statement

I am currently trying to learn about using pointers and functions together in C, which I don't think is easy. 
I am trying to print the last element in an array, it actually does the opposite and prints the first element. 
I know people normally use for loops, but I can't figure out how to do that with exactly this kind of problem and therefore I thought that I would try it out with an if statement instead.

**Edit:**
Why is if statement not working in this case? It seems logic that it should work...

My main.c file:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"
#define Size 7

int main(void) 
{

    int array1[] = { 11, 88, 5, 9, 447, 8, 68, 4 };

    maxValue(array1, Size);

    return 0;
}
```

My functions.h file:

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

int maxValue(const int *, int);

#endif
```

My functions.c file:

```cpp
#include "functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int maxValue(const int *array1, int Size)
{

    int max = array1[0];

    if (max < array1[Size]) {
        Size++;
        max = array1[Size];
    }

    printf("Max value: %d \n", max);
}
```

Comment: Explain clearly what you intend to achieve, because printing the last element is trivially simple and needs neither a loop or a conditional, so your code and your statement about what "people normally" do make no sense.  Either what you want to do is more complex than stated or you are very lost.

Answer (score 0):

*Why is if statement not working in this case? It seems logic that it should work...?* Because here

```
if (max < array1[Size]) { }
```

`Size` is defined as `7` and you are comparing `array1[0]` with `array1[7]` i.e `11 < 4` -> false, hence it doesn't enter into `if` block, so the last `printf` executes and that prints `max`. But its not a correct logic if `if` blocks becomes true then further `Size++` will cause accessing out of bound array elements which cause **undefined behavior**.

```
int maxValue(const int *array1, int Size)
{
    int max = array1[0];
    if (max < array1[Size]) { /* 11 < 4 false, skips if block */
        //Size++; /* this is wrong as Size++ here and next accessing array1[Size] cause UB due to accessing out of bound array element */
        max = array1[Size];
    }
    printf("Max value: %d \n", max); /* max is stills array1[0] i.e 11 */
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. But your code finds the largest value in the array. I might not have made it clear that I meant to find the integer that holds the last place in the array.

Comment: So I meant the integer 4.

Comment: @Achal Does your function needs to return something?

Comment: @kiranBiradar Its better to return as OP mentioned return type as `int`.

Comment: @TheCNewbie I edited the answer. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: @Achal OP wants to print/return last element not to find max in it(`array1[LastIndex]` should be it).

Answer (score 0):

Let's simulate what the CPU does when it enters the maxValue function with those arguments. **1.** The variable `max` is assigned the value of `array1[0]`, which is 11.
**2.** If `max` (11) is less than `array1[7]` (4). It is not, so the `if` block is not executed.
**3.** Print `max`: print 11.

Another thing: Your program causes undefined behaviour. Let's take an example where `array1[0]` is 3, instead of 11. The if block will be executed (3 < 4), so:
`Size` is incremented to 8.
`max` is assigned `array1[8]`. Since the last index in `array1` is 7 (that is how you declared the array), you are accessing a memory adress which you are not supposed to access. This is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The names `maxValue()` and `max` are misleading and confusing what you are trying to do.  `lastValue()` and `last` would make much more sense.

However what you are trying to do makes no sense in C because arrays are of known length, so you can access the last element directly:

```
int array1[] = { 11, 88, 5, 9, 447, 8, 68, 4 };
int array_length = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(*array1) ;
printf("Lastvalue: %d \n", array1[array_length - 1] ) ;
```

However you cannot do this in a function because arrays are not first class data types in C and when passed to a function will "degrade" to a simple pointer without any information regarding the size of the array pointed to.  The calling function having the size information must pass that too (as you have done, but then appeared to get very confused):

```
void printLast( int* array, int length )
{
    printf( "Lastvalue: %d \n", array1[length - 1] ) ;
}
```

It is difficult to see why you thought you might need any other code or what your `maxValue()` function is intended to achieve.  The "logic" which you say "should work" is thus:

> If value of the first array element is less than the value of the last array element, then print the *undefined* value one past the end of the array; otherwise print the first element of the array.

If you wanted to print the last element, then you simply print it, the value of the first element has nothing to do do with it.  Either way you should not index past the end of the array - that value is undefined.